# How to move infoWindow in google map API

Tags: reactjs, marker

I have an issue with displaying the infoWindow in Google Maps API in create-react-app. The matter is that is hides the marker when it is clicked. Is it possible to somehow move this infoWindow a bit higher above the marker?

here is the repo https://github.com/Lexie14/Neighborhood-Map

[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbTwl.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code in sample code snippet instead of github link

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<InfoWindow
  options={{
    pixelOffset: new window.google.maps.Size(
      0, -30
    )
  }}
  position={{
    lat: 1.234,
    lng: 5.1234
  }}
>
  <div>
    Hello World!!
  </div>
</InfoWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [`InfoWindowOptions.pixelOffset` property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions.pixelOffset) to set offset in pixels, here is an example how to set it for `google-maps-react` `InfoWindow`:

```
<InfoWindow 
     pixelOffset={new google.maps.Size(0,-48)}
     position={this.state.selectedItem.position}
     visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
     <div>
       <h1>{this.state.selectedItem.title}</h1>
     </div>
</InfoWindow>
```

---

There is also another option where info window position could be adjusted automatically, for that matter `marker` (anchor) property needs to be specified instead of `position`:

```
<InfoWindow
    marker={this.state.activeMarker}
    visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow} >
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.selectedItem.title}</h1>
    </div>
 </InfoWindow>
```

[Here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n1pxy250pl) for your reference